# Forward a stream using ffmeg

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

I have a RTMP stream that I receive on a Raspberry PI,nginx, port 1935, works fine, can play the stream with:

```
ffplay rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live
```

Ultimate target is to add a 15 sec delay, this should be possible with a TPAD filter, but, before i start working on that, I want it to work without delay.

I've read docs and other resources and came to this:

```
./ffmpeg -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live -c copy -f rtsp rtsp://127.0.0.1:1936/live
```

Running this command gives no errors, but no stream is available on port 1936 either (testing with ffplay **ffplay rtsp://127.0.0.1:1936/live**

Port 1936 is setup in nginx config and if I stream to that port I can play the stream too in ffplay.

ffmpeg version 6.0-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516

Hope one of you guys can point me in the right direction.